# Using C++20 concept/requires for function partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts

I'm learning C++20 concept/requires. I would like to implement a function for getting the sum of an integer list with template meta programming:

```
sum<IntList<1, 2, 3>>();
```

As it's known that C++ standards don't allow function partial specialization, I would like to use C++20 concept/requires to the similar stuff as function partial specialization.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int...N>
class IntList;

template<int...N>
concept IsIntList = IntList<N...>{};

template<typename T>
int sum() {
    return 0;
}

template<int...N>
requires IsIntList<N...>
int sum() {
    return (N + ...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << sum<IntList<1, 2>>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it could not produce what I want. Put my code in [C++ Insights](https://cppinsights.io). The first `sum` is instantiated, instead of the second `sum`.

Here is the result of C++Insights:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int...N>
class IntList;

template<int...N>
concept IsIntList = IntList<N...>{};

template<typename T>
int sum() {
    return 0;
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:21 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
int sum<IntList<1, 2> >()
{
  return 0;
}
#endif


template<int...N>
requires IsIntList<N...>
int sum() {
    return (N + ...);
}

int main()
{
  std::cout.operator<<(sum<IntList<1, 2> >()).operator<<(std::endl);
  return 0;
}
```

What's the correct way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be yet another version of the "here is a template; I want to know if this type is a specialization of that template" question.

Answer (score 3):

The central problem you're encountering is that you have a type template parameter whose type you want to be constrained to being some specialization of some template. That's not a thing you can do with a `requires` clause. At least, not easily.

It's best to avoid this problem. You're only encountering it because you insist that `sum`'s template parameter must be some specialization of `IntList` instead of the integers themselves directly. The best way to handle this is by ditching this assumption:

```
template<int... Ints>
constexpr int sum(IntList<Ints...>)
{ return (0 + ... + Ints); }
```

You then call this function as so: `sum(IntList<1, 2>{})`. Note that `IntList` needs to have a `constexpr` default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the concept of `IsIntList` is wrong, it only evaluates the value of `IntList<N...>{}`, and since `IntList` is not a `bool` type, `IsIntList` always return false.

You should use template partial specialization to define the `IsIntList`.

```
template<int...N>
class IntList;

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool IsIntList = false;
template<int...N>
inline constexpr bool IsIntList<IntList<N...>> = true;
```

For a specialized version of the `sum`, just constrain `IsIntList<T>` to be true, then you can extract the value of the `IntList` with the help of a tag class and template lambda to calculate the sum.

```
template<class>
struct tag{};

template<class T>
  requires IsIntList<T>
int sum() {
  return []<int...N>(tag<IntList<N...>>) 
    { return (N + ... + 0); }(tag<T>{});
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/b58T1z3eY)